# How to load image from remote url in Kotlin Compose desktop?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

How to load image from remote url in Kotlin Compose desktop?

in Android it use coli as official sample

```
@Composable
fun NetworkImage(
    url: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    placeholderColor: Color? = MaterialTheme.colors.compositedOnSurface(0.2f)
) {
    CoilImage(
        data = url,
        modifier = modifier,
        contentScale = contentScale,
        loading = {
            if (placeholderColor != null) {
                Spacer(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(placeholderColor)
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

bu as desktop application, aar is not supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`javax.imageio.ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to load an image from network:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.asImageBitmap
import org.jetbrains.skija.Image
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

fun loadNetworkImage(link: String): ImageBitmap {
    val url = URL(link)
    val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    connection.connect()

    val inputStream = connection.inputStream
    val bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream)

    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", stream)
    val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()

    return Image.makeFromEncoded(byteArray).asImageBitmap()
}
```

And then use it as:

```
Image(
    bitmap = loadNetworkImage("Your image link")
)
```

Comment: actually , I finding the solution to act like Glide or Coli for fetching, decoding, and displaying an Image which from a remote url, and with the state of pause, resume, etc.  but thx @Saurabh Thorat

Comment: Note, this also can work for files not from a URL, since it uses bytes to pipe through `Image.makeFromEncoded()`. In my own context, I was getting a file from JFileChooser, and used `org.jetbrains.skija.Image` in this way.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way I found was to use ktor to get the image as a byteArray and then use the Kotlin function makeFromEncoded to create a ImageBitmap which can then be used in a Composable Image

```
suspend fun loadPicture(url: String): ImageBitmap {
    val image = ktorHttpClient.use { client ->
        client.get<ByteArray>(url)
    }
    return Image.makeFromEncoded(image).asImageBitmap()
}
```

Then inside your composable

```
if (imageBitmap != null) {
    Image(bitmap = imageBitmap, "content description")
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks.
I had to modify : with kotlin 1.8.20 compose 1.4.0 kto 2.2.4

```
suspend fun loadPicture(url: String): ImageBitmap {
    val httpClient = HttpClient {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                useAlternativeNames = false
            })
        }
    }
    val image: ByteArray = httpClient.use { client ->
        client.get(url).body()
    }
    return Image.makeFromEncoded(image).toComposeImageBitmap()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I found.

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toComposeImageBitmap
import org.jetbrains.skia.Image
import java.net.URL

fun loadImage(url: String) =
    Image.makeFromEncoded(URL(url).readBytes())
        .toComposeImageBitmap()
```

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me.

```
fun loadImage(url: String): ImageBitmap {
    return ImageIO.read(URL(url)).toComposeImageBitmap()
}
```

You can then use

```
Image(
    bitmap = loadImage(imageUrl),
    contentDescription = null
)
```